# LINQ to XML - Elements() works but Elements(XName) does not work

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Given below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
    <Body>
        <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="txtCurrentDate">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                                <Value>=Today()</Value>
                                <Style>
                                    <FontWeight>Medium</FontWeight>
                                    <Format>d</Format>
                                </Style>
                            </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                            <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                    </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <Left>0.36958in</Left>
                <Height>0.22917in</Height>
                <Width>1in</Width>
                <Style>
                    <Border>
                        <Style>None</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
            </Textbox>
            <Textbox Name="txtName">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                                <Value>Mark Wilkinson</Value>
                                <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <Top>0.22917in</Top>
                <Left>0.36958in</Left>
                <Height>0.20833in</Height>
                <Width>3.22917in</Width>
                <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
                <Style>
                    <Border>
                        <Style>None</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
            </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>6.01667in</Height>
        <Style />
    </Body>
    <Width>7.92333in</Width>   
</Report>
```

I want to get all the **Textbox** names and values. This is what I tried and it does not work:

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load("..\\..\\testxml.rdl");

            var elements = from c in data.Elements("ReportItems")
                           select c;
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Element : " + element.Attribute("Name").Value);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

but when I change the query to something like this

```
var elements = from c in data.Elements().Elements().ElementAt(0).Elements().ElementAt(0).Elements()
                           select c;
```

it works.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Edit: With the help of answers I was able to get the desired results. Thank you so much :)

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load("..\\..\\testxml.rdl");            
            XNamespace ns = data.Root.Name.Namespace;
            var elements = from c in data.Descendants(ns + "Textbox")
                           select c;
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Element : " + element.Attribute("Name").Value);                
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

TIA.

Raja

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to take the namespace into account:

```
XNamespace df = data.Root.Name.Namespace;
```

Then use `df + "foo"` to select elements with local name `foo` in the namespace defined on the root element.

And as already mentioned you probably want to select descendants, not child elements:

```
        var elements = from c in data.Descendants(df + "Textbox")
                       select c;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer but why would i need the name space for?

Comment: If the XML input uses namespaces then with the XML API in System.Xml.Linq you need to construct an `XName` by "adding" an `XNamespace` to a string with the local name.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `Descendants()` not `Elements()` in this case.  `Elements()` only selects immediate children.

**Documentation**

- [XContainer.Descendants Method (XName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) - Returns a filtered collection of the *descendant elements* for this document or element, in document order. Only elements that have a matching XName are included in the collection
- [XContainer.Elements Method (XName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) - Returns a filtered collection of the *child elements* of this element or document, in document order. Only elements that have a matching XName are included in the collection.

*Note: Based on your sample code, using `Descendants()` will still throw an exception because not all of the `ReportItems` elements have a `Name` attribute.  You need to do something like `Console.WriteLine("Element : " + (element.Attributes("Name").Any() ? element.Attribute("Name").Value : "(no name)") );`*

Comment: You've only solved half the problem - there is a namespace issue here too.

Comment: @Rob Levine, Are you sure?  It doesn't seem necessary, but maybe I'm missing something.  Enlighten me.

Comment: The xml the OP has supplied is in a namespace of "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" (scroll to the right on the first line). This means that although you correctly identified the descendants issue, the OP's call to data.Descendants("ReportItems") will still return nothing as this is searching for ReportItems in the "null" namespace. It needs to be namespace prefixed (see Martin's answer), or look like this: data.Descendants(XName.Get("ReportItems", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" )

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filepath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {

                XElement xe = XElement.Load(filepath);
              // 

                string sql = "insert OR IGNORE into price_list (name,his_code,specs,unit,spell,price) values(@name,@his_code,@specs,@unit,@spell,@price);";
                int count = 0;
                foreach (XElement el in xe.Descendants("row"))
                {
                    SQLiteParameter[] ps =
                    {
                        new SQLiteParameter("@his_code",el.Element("aka079").Value),
                        new SQLiteParameter("@name",el.Element("aka061").Value),
                        new SQLiteParameter("@specs",el.Element("aka073").Value),
                        new SQLiteParameter("@unit",el.Element("aka067").Value),
                        new SQLiteParameter("@spell",SpellCode.GetSpellCode(el.Element("aka061").Value)),
                        new SQLiteParameter("@price",el.Element("aka071").Value),
                    };

                    if (SqliteHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, ps) > 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

**just change XElements() to Descendants(),it will work probably**